# Проблема с организацией логики столкновения шарика и кирпичей

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, математика, xna, monogame

Написал игру Break Out на фреймворке Monogame на C#. Но написал ее далеко не идеально, ибо шарик у меня изображен через квадрат, где изображен круг на прозрачном фоне.

У меня возникает проблема с огранизацией логики столкновения шарика и кирпичей.

Не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы высчитывался диапазон X координат, где они (Х координаты шарика и Х координаты отдельного кирпича) должны пересечься.

Сейчас метод, который вычисляет кирпич, который сталкивается с шариком, выглядит вот так:

```
private int BallContactCoords()
{
   int smallestRangeIndex = -1;
   double CenterOfBallCoordsX = ball.X + ball.Radius;

   for (int i = 0; i < breaks.Length; i++)
   {
      if (breaks[i] != null && 
 (ball.Y <= breaks[i].Y + breaks[i].Height) && 
 (Math.Abs(CenterOfBallCoordsX - (breaks[i].X + breaks[i].Width / 2)) <= breaks[i].Width))
      {
         if (smallestRangeIndex == -1)
            smallestRangeIndex = i;
         else
         {
            if ( Math.Abs(CenterOfBallCoordsX - (breaks[i].X + breaks[i].Width / 2))
< Math.Abs(CenterOfBallCoordsX - (breaks[smallestRangeIndex].X 
+ breaks[smallestRangeIndex].Width / 2)) )
            {
               smallestRangeIndex = i;
            }
         }
      }
   }
   return smallestRangeIndex;
}
```

Он ищет тот кирпич, который имеет меньшее расстояние до средней Х-координаты шарика, то есть Х-координата "квадрата" (в нем изображен шарик) + радиус круга, затем возвращает его.

Но не всегда это работает. Ибо тогда считается, что этот шарик это и есть квадрат. И тогда крайние стенки квадрата - тоже! Но ведь не должны.. Ибо это круг, и у него нет этих краев как у квадрата.

Я пытался придумать какой-нибудь другой алгоритм, придумывал и воплощал например такой:

Проверить, на одной ли высоте шарик и кирпич или шарик ниже, если да, то:
    вычислить элемент диапазона, который будет равняться (высота кирпича - высота шарика)
    теперь диапазон будет таков: средний X шарика - элемент диапазона >= Х кирпича (крайняя левая точка кирпича) && средний Х шарика + элемент диапазона <= X кирпича + его ширина (то есть крайняя правая точка)

Но и он не срабатывал!
Идея состояла в том, чтобы рассчитать, каково расстояние от левого края шарика на этом Y до правого края шарика на этом Y может быть, и сравнить два этих диапазона (диапазон Х шарика и диапазон Х кирпича).

Пожалуйста, подскажите мне, как можно вплоть до пикселя (размер шарика 30х30) понимать, когда он притронулся к кирпичу, а когда нет. Ибо когда нет - это мог быть угол квадрата.

Вот ссылка на полный код, если он здесь нужен: https://pastebin.com/qEHRVybU

Comment: для начала, вам нужна параметрическая формула шарика в прямоугольной системе координат: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0
далее, вы просто проверяете на сколько удален центр вашего шарика от кирпича, потом сравниваете значение, если оно меньше значения по заданному углу, вы получаете столкновение.

Comment: Пожалуйста, объясните подробнее, я плохо понял то, что вы предложили.

Comment: 1 - определяем положение центра шарика и преграды(кирпича)
2 - проверяем расстояния между центром и поверхностями преград, если оно более радиуса вашего шарика, то действуем далее, если нет то проверяем в направлении преграды границу шарика, если они пересекают границы преграды или касаются, то столкновение.
Как-то так.

Answer (score 0):

У шарика есть центр и радуис. Когда проверяешь столкновение считай расстояние от центра шарика до кирпича, если результат равен радиусу или меньше - столкновение.

Comment: Только не до кирпича а до множества точек лежащих на периметре кирпича

Comment: вот тут то и проблема в том, что если радиус 15, то он состоит из Х и У, которые могут быть 2 и 13, 1 и 14, 0 и 15, 15 и 0 и т.д...

Comment: Чего-о-о-о? Каким это образом радиус вообще связан с координатами? Радиус это прямая линия, соединяющая центр с любой точкой окружности или поверхности шара. У радиуса может быть только один параметр - длина, т.к. это прямая линия.

Comment: ну вот представьте круг, и он его центра проведен отрезок к краю этого круга с углом 45 градусов. Вы хотите сказать что этот отрезок не будет равняться радиусу? 
Будет, но при этом этот отрезок был повернут вправо вверх, а значит X и Y возрастали. 
Но если бы длина изменения обоих X и Y координат равнялась радиусу, то отрезок был бы начерчен до угла квадрата, который можно описать вокруг этого круга.

Соответственно X координата была изменена допустим (допустим) наполовину от радиуса, также как и Y.  А не оба эти координаты были изменены на 1 радиус.

Comment: Просто пытаюсь понять закономерность, как высчитывать, насколько изменяется Х, а насколько Y. как описать этот диапазон и так далее.

Comment: Вот тут описывается, определение столкновения круга и  линии https://stackoverflow.com/a/1084899/1536742 Никаких заумностей, только центр круга, радиус круга, начало/конец отрезка. Никаких лишних сущностей не надо выдумывать.